# Изменение позиции diva после каждого клика

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function handler() {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.left = "100px";

}

</script>
```

это меняет положение diva один раз подскажите как сделать чтобы положение менялось после каждого последующего нажатия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function handler(p) {
    var e = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    e.style.left = p?(parseInt(e.style.left||0)+p)+"px":"";
}
</script>
```

Comment: как возвратить div в изначальное положение?

Comment: `document.getElementById("myDIV").style.left = '';`

Comment: эту строку куда надо добавить? создать новую функцию?

Comment: внёс правки. вписывайте на сколько нужно сменить положение div `handler(100)` или что бы вернуть его на место `handler(0)`

Comment: все равно что то не пойму как мне это сделать нужно создавать новый handler? или заменить параметр е?

Comment: я всё уже сделал и внёс все изменения в ответ. используйте так же функцию `handler(100)`, а если хотите вернуть на место то `handler(0)`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: не забудьте принять ответ, если он вам подходит

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function handler(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.left = new String(event.currentTarget.offsetLeft+100) + "px";
}
</script>
```

надеюсь это то что нужно